# DefaultChannelPipeline exception from JBOSS Server Logs

Tags: java, spring, couchbase

I am building an application which uses Couchbase NoSQL. I am using spring to connect to couchbase. Though the application functioning is proper but the server logs are getting flooded with a number of exceptions. Please help. The stack trace is as below-:

```
WARN  [com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline] (cb-io-1-3) An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.: com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@447a718b rejected from java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor@54afe887[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 139]
        at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:99)
        at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec.channelRead(MessageToMessageCodec.java:111)
        at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
        at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
        at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265)
        at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:147)
        at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
        at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
        at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
        at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
        at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
        at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)

    Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@447a718b rejected from java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor@54afe887[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 139]
    at rx.Observable$27.onError(Observable.java:7996)
    at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError(SafeSubscriber.java:158)
    at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onError(SafeSubscriber.java:119)
    at rx.subjects.SubjectSubscriptionManager$SubjectObserver.onError(SubjectSubscriptionManager.java:226)
    at rx.subjects.AsyncSubject.onError(AsyncSubject.java:115)




Caused by: com.couchbase.client.core.CouchbaseException: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@447a718b rejected from java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor@54afe887[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 139]
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@447a718b rejected from java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor@54afe887[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 139]

07:38:51,399 WARN  [com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline] (cb-io-1-4) An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.: com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@6d3f29fc rejected from java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor@70a23052[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 149]
        at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:99)
        at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec.channelRead(MessageToMessageCodec.java:111)


        07:39:21,413 WARN  [com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractGenericHandler] (cb-io-1-3) [rhlappomr665.fairisaac.com/172.24.14.208:8093][QueryEndpoint]: Caught unknown exception: rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@569ed0a4 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor@220fdd2e[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 141]: com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@569ed0a4 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor@220fdd2e[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 141]
```